# Disable particular tests through Annotation Transformer : TestNG

Tags: java, testing, junit, annotations, testng

I have a huge project with numerous test cases. Some test cases are suppose to work on only particular environments and some are not. So I'm trying to skip or disable tests which don't belong to that environment.

I'm using Annotation Transformers to override @Test 's behaviour.

Here is my Transformer code in

```
package com.raghu.listener

public class SkipTestsTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass,
            Constructor testConstructor, java.lang.reflect.Method testMethod){

//          I intend to do this later
//          if(someCondition){
//              // Do something.
//          }
                System.out.println("Inside Transform");
    }
}
```

As of now I'm just trying to print.

I have many packages and classes on which I have to impose this Transformer.

How and Where should I initiate this class?

Please suggest any better methods for doing the same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IAnnotationTransformer is a listener. You do not need to instantiate it, testng would do it for you. You can specify a listener in any of the listed ways [here.](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners), either through your xmls or through service loaders, depending upon your test environment.

If you do not have groups marked in your testcases, then I think this is the way to go by setting the enabled attribute to false.  There is another way to skip a test in IInvokedMethodListener, but I do not see any benefit of one over the other.

Comment: Thanks so much niharika_neo. I was struggling with this. As it turns out we can't specify a listener by @Listener annotation for IAnnotationTransformer. It should be included in the xml file.

Comment: Can u please tell me how to send parameters to annoation transformer implementation.?

Comment: I do not think there is a way to get that in iannotationtransformer.  You can get it in iinvokedmethodlistener though

Comment: Whats your use case?  If you are using suite level parameters, you might be setting them to some static constants to be used across your tests. - in which case you can directly refer them

Comment: Use case to skip certain tests that belongs various environments. So I need to pass environment information to my annotation transformer at run time. Right now I'm setting up an environment variable and accessing it in my transformer class.